# Nested if in SQL Server

Tags: database

this is my query :

1. if (a)
2. begin
3. ---
4. ---
5. ---
6. if (b)
7. ---
8. else
9. ---
10. end

when I remove 3 lines of this query ( line 6 and 7 and 8 ), it works ,, what's wrong with that query when I have all the lines

I should say the line 7 is just this : "return -23"  and the line 9 is just this : delete tablename where ..

### I mean as I know the second If doesn't need begin and end (?)

my main query is this :
if  @Updatekind = 2
BEGIN
        Delete SALFactorAddOns
        Where SerialNoFhsFAO = @SerialNoFHS
                and (CompanyNo = @CompanyNoFHS)

if ((select invsnfhs from SALFactorHds where    (SerialNoFHS = @SerialNoFHS) 
                and (CompanyNo = @CompanyNoFHS)  ) > 0 )

```
            return -23
```

else
    DELETE      SALFactorHds
        WHERE       (SerialNoFHS = @SerialNoFHS) 
                and (CompanyNo = @CompanyNoFHS) 
end

Comment: Post the entire query with error messages

Comment: You need to provide the whole 10 lines of code to make others understand!

Comment: I should say the line 7 is just this : "return -23"  and the line 9 is just this : delete tablename where ..

Answer (score 0):

An If statement go with keywords BEGIN and END (statement block), if there is no statement block used, the IF or ELSE condition can affect the performance of only one Transact-SQL statement.

```
IF @a is null
Begin
-- code here 
End
```

Read more about the syntax [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: I should say the line 7 is just this : "return -23" and the line 9 is just this : delete tablename where .. I mean as I know the second If doesn't need begin and end

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question , I added That part of query , if the second if is true there is nothing wrong with program , if not it wont check the esle statement ! when I type the parameters by myself the is nothing wrong and the esle statement will work ,, but it doesn't work by runing sp

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the construct:

```
if (a) 
  begin
  ...
  end
else if (b)
  begin
  ...
  end
else 
  begin
  ...
  end
```

?